# Is this dust inside Retina Display on my Macbook Pro 13 inch?

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I have a late 2015 13 Inch Macbook Pro with Retina Display, and here are the pics of that. Could anyone please suggest how do I get these spots of my screen?

Regards,
Bengalurean

[image: macbook pro retina display]

Comment: Have you checked whether it's actually on top of the screen? - Looks a bit like grease from the keyboard that's smeared over the screen.

Comment: Yes I have checked it, and repeatedly tried to clean it with screen cleaning fluids. Here is another image of that.. 

http://imgur.com/a/lk99M

Comment: Was it like this when you bought it? - If not, did it occur gradually or all at once?

Comment: No. This started appearing after 1.5 years after I bought it.. It was spotless before. I tried to clean it, but it appears its inside the screen.

Comment: Very odd. I don't think it looks like dust at all. It could look a bit like the problem some people were having that the anti-reflective coating starts to peel of after a while. Apple started a quality program for this and extended warranties up to 3 years from date of original purchase as far as I remember. Try contacting Apple to see if they would replace the screen under warranty!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have contacted support, and they confirmed its an issue with anti-reflective coating. I am getting it replaced.

Comment: Super - good to know that the quality program is effective!

Answer (score 2):

Judging by your photo's this is not dust but the anti-reflective coating peeling of the screen.
As jksoegaard correctly states in the comments, apple has an extended warranty in place for this issue.
This [article](https://www.macrumors.com/2017/02/24/apple-extended-anti-reflective-repair-program/) tells you more about it, and [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7651670?start=0&tstart=0) it is mentioned on apple's forum.

You should contact your nearest apple service provider, they are very likely to replace your display for free.